# Github Actions Fails while building react app

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions

I am trying to build the react app using the github actions.

I tried setting the below workflow.
I google and found out it is running on low memory.

```
name: Node CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm install, build
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm build
      env:
        CI: true

    - name: deploy to s3
      uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
      with:
        args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
      env:
        SOURCE_DIR: './public'
        AWS_REGION: 'us-east-1'
        AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Error throws like

```
Creating an optimized production build...
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: using node-version to 12x solves the problem.